# Mongodb $inc returns double

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm trying to set the `_id` as an auto increment `Int` as stated in the Documentation https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/ Which is working almost fine but when trying to insert the records the function is returning the value as a `double` instead of `integer` So i tried the below changes.

```
db.system.js.save({
_id : "getNextId",
value : function (name) {
    var ret = db.counters.findAndModify(
        {
            query: { _id: name },
            update: { $inc: { seq: 1 } },
            new: true
        }
    );
    return Math.ceil(ret.seq);  //not working
    //return parseInt(ret.seq); //not working
   }    
 });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript only has the floating point `Number` type for all numerical values so you have to use [`NumberInt`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/shell-types/#numberint) and [`NumberLong`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/shell-types/#numberlong) objects in the shell to represent true integer values in MongoDB.

So what `parseInt` is doing is parsing an integer-formatted string, but returning that value as a floating point `Number`. And as you've discovered, you need to wrap the numerical value in one of the integer objects for MongoDB to store the value as an integer in the database:

```
return NumberInt(ret.seq);  // For 32-bit integers

return NumberLong(ret.seq); // for 64-bit integers
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I tried this, it's working fine

```
db.system.js.save({
_id : "getNextId",
value : function (name) {
    var ret = db.counters.findAndModify(
        {
            query: { _id: name },
            update: { $inc: { seq: 1 } },
            new: true
        }
    );
    return NumberLong(ret.seq); //working
}    
});
```